# Cancel on modal confirmation dialog not working

Tags: 2010, jquery, form, modal-dialog

I have a simple modal popup dialog launched on the "register" button of a "new element" form :

```
$( "#ctl00_m_g_9ff78e92_ed40_4212_ae0f_44b787664fa8_ctl00_toolBarTbl_RightRptControls_ctl00_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem" ).click(function() {


            if (confirm("Confirmez-vous ce choix de réforme ? : ")) {

             }
             else {
                 return false;
             }


    });

})
```

The dialog is launched but the "Cancel" doesn't work: the element is created anyway.

I've tried different way of returning the false method but same problem each time.

**EDIT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$( "#ctl00_m_g_9ff78e92_ed40_4212_ae0f_44b787664fa8_ctl00_toolBarTbl_RightRptControls_ctl00_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem" ).click(function() {


        function PreSaveAction() {   
           if (confirm("Confirmez-vous ce choix de réforme ? : ")) {
                return true;
           }
           else {
                return false;
           }
        }
         //OpenConfigurationDialog("Confirmez-vous ce choix de réforme ?");


        PreSaveAction();


    });

})
```

Comment: Is `ctl00_m_g_9ff78e92_ed40_4212_ae0f_44b787664fa8_ctl00_toolBarTbl_RightRptControls_ctl00_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem` the save button? Or is it a custom button?

Comment: the save button

Comment: Then you just need to delete all of your javascript, and replace it with JayHell's code.

Comment: Ok thanks his answer is good but thanks for explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the PreSaveAction in order to cancel the save.

```
    function PreSaveAction() {   
       if (confirm("Confirmez-vous ce choix de réforme ? : ")) {
            return true;
       }
       else {
            return false;
       }
    }
```

Comment: thanks but doing like that (see my edited question)
 it doesn't work

Comment: It's not necessary to wrap it in jQuery or bind it to any button... if the function is in the page, upon the Save action it will get fired.

Comment: sorry I'm not very good in jquery neither sharepoint for the moment. Can you explain me what I could do better and how?

Comment: you could simply put that code into a JavaScript file, then edit the "NewForm" webpart to add the link for JS Link (Miscellaneous section | JS Link : ~sitecollection/pathtofile/file.js)

Comment: I just replace all and put it directly in the html      Thanks